# How to prevent getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException "without reason"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, parsing, https

I'm working on a Spring Boot project.

I develope it when I have time in the office, so from Monday to Friday, from 8:00am to 4:00pm.
When I use, and test it sometimes 8 hours long, everything works fine. But usually once per day at night it gives me this `Exception` **without any action** (I am totally away from keyboard):

```
o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:683) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_272]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_272]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_272]
```

I have searched for it in Stackoverflow, and in many threads I have found:
"This exception can occur when you try to execute HTTPS request from client on endpoint which isn't HTTPS enabled."

I don't use SSL at all, and I use the application only via http://localhost:port or http://IP:port.

So what could this mysterious https request be, and how could I **prevent** getting this Exception?

Comment: Could some other application on your machine be calling https://localhost:port on a schedule? Is it the same time every night? You could use a tool like Wireshark or look into Tomcat access logs to see where the request originates.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any scheduled task. It happens on different times, but usually once per day in the "idle" time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "for no reason"

There is always a reason. It's a computer, it has no ability to just sass you.

You haven't given much detail about your setup. Most likely, this box is accessible in one way or another from the outside world, and some portscanner or whatnot is hitting your service. That's what happens when you put things on the public internet.

You may want to use a firewall or change some configs to ensure this server is not publically accessible.

If you *do* want it to be accessible, then the right move isn't to supress this stuff, but to ensure that it is going to the right place. Some log file so you can look back, do analysis, if security issues occur, that you can look back, etc.

Comment: I have turned on the tomcat access log, and found this in the time of the Exception: `167.248.133.40 - - [01/Dec/2020:09:29:46 +0100] "-" 400 435`After google it I have landed here: https://www.proxydocker.com/en/iplookup/167.248.133.40. I live in Hungary.

Comment: Yup. Spammy web bot. You should firewall this box or find another way to ensure it is not publicly accessible on the open internet, or take a crash course in how to manage open servers in a secure fashion, ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:422)
```

This is saying that a http request is being processed. If you look at the sourcecode of Http11InputBuffer you will see that it's trying to process request phrase 2, the highlighted part in the following example. For example "GET **/wiki/Hoofdpagina** HTTP/1.1"

So a call is definitely made to your server with a possibly unparsable
request url.
Assume an attack on your server, for example it could be a path traversal attempt.
Set the logging on debug so see more info. For even more info on the source of the request.